# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add a searchBox to my Google Maps API map, I already activated placesAPI but when I try to call it I get this error: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null"
in the file "place imps.js".
This file is not mine, must be a parte of Google Places API.
 Here is my code (which is working fine until I add the part of the searchBox):

```
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 9,
scrollwheel: false,
center: center,
styles: mapStyles,
disableDefaultUI: false          
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;

// Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
var input = document.getElementById('location');
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
return map;
}

var center = {lat:38.655942,lng:-8.200984};
init_map(locations, center);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem (preferably a StackOverflow code snippet in the question).

Comment: it might be helpful to other users if you include whetehr `ownerDocument` is something you've defined or something that is internal to Google Maps API. Also, format your code for better readability. We, as a SO community, don't have the same context as you do. We don't know the line number, or whether your code is in a module or something. Until you get better at using StackOverflow, please err on the side of providing more context than you think is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I've been battling this issue for hours and just fixed the problem for myself.  I am unsure how you are including your various placeholders and placement  tags but somewhere you need to include:

```
<div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
    <div>
        <div id="title">
          Autocomplete search
        </div>
    <div id="type-selector" class="pac-controls">
          <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
          <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

          <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
          <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

          <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-address">
          <label for="changetype-address">Addresses</label>

          <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
          <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
        </div>
        <div id="strict-bounds-selector" class="pac-controls">
          <input type="checkbox" id="use-strict-bounds" value="">
          <label for="use-strict-bounds">Strict Bounds</label>
        </div>
      </div>
  <div id="pac-container">
    <input id="pac-input" type="text"
       placeholder="Enter a location">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
  <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
```

When I first encountered the error I had a map being drawn with the correct lat/lon that were hardcoded in for the original center point when the map was         loaded.  By adding the above code before/after the  that created the actual map the autocomplete box appeared and my error disappeared.  Hopefully this helps and if anything is unclear or confusing in my answer let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an olde at this point but be sure to check that the '***input***' that is being passed into the '**new google.maps.places.SearchBox(*input*)**' is not null or you will get this error.

Comment: please, use code formatting for code blocks instead of bold